# Windows Form App C# Proper way to call DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have 3 classes that refer to one another for my windows form app.

Each class has its own specific database calls.

However, I am unsure if this is the right way to call refer to them as I get a stack overflow exception when I start my program now

When I debugged, I realised that as I called on each class, it reloads the dbcontext each time. Is that okay?

```
public class ProgramsData
{
    private AutoPrintDbContext dbContext = new AutoPrintDbContext();
    private FieldsData fieldsData = new FieldsData();
    private PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();

    public ProgramsData()
    {

    }
}

public class PrinterData
{
    private AutoPrintDbContext dbContext = new AutoPrintDbContext();
    private ProgramsData programsData = new ProgramsData();
    private FieldsData fieldsData = new FieldsData();

    public PrinterData()
    {

    }
}

public class FieldsData
{
    private AutoPrintDbContext dbContext = new AutoPrintDbContext();
    PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();

    public FieldsData()
    {

    }
}
```

This is how I call my classes in the main program:

```
public partial class AutoPrint : Form
{
    ProgramsData programsData = new ProgramsData();
    PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();

    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var backgroundWorker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        List<PrintObject> pol = new List<PrintObject>();
        pol = printerData.Load(InputDirectory.Text, programInput.Text);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is OK.   DbContext is a very lightweight object, and it is meant to be instantiated each time you want to make a data request.

Comment: But the issue is that I get a StackOverflow Exception when I instantiate those classes in my main program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `StackOverflowException` has nothing to do with your database context of Entity Framework.  It's your class properties.

What's the first thing that happens when you create an instance of `PrinterData`?  It creates an instance of FieldsData:

```
private FieldsData fieldsData = new FieldsData();
```

When it creates that instance, what's the first thing that instance does?  It creates an instance of `PrinterData`:

```
PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();
```

When it creates that instance, what's the first thing that instance does?  It creates an instance of `FieldsData`:

```
private FieldsData fieldsData = new FieldsData();
```

When it creates that instance, what's the first thing that instance does?  It creates an instance of `PrinterData`:

```
PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();
```

... and so on indefinitely.  (Your `ProgramsData` is also part of this pattern.)

Don't do that.

Whatever these classes are, whatever they do or represent in your design, they can't mutually depend on each other in this way.  Without any other information about your design or the needs of the system I can't really be more specific other than to say that you should remove these fields from your classes so they don't mutually depend on one another infinitely.

Perhaps at the top level of your program you would simply want one instance of each class.  And if any given method from one class requires an instance of another class to perform some operation, you can pass it the instance you have instead of creating a new one.

There's *probably* still a better way to design whatever you're working on, but again I can't really speak to that.  Only to the cause of the exception.

As for the data context, you *probably* don't want that to be globally created in every class all over the place either.  Perhaps also have just one top-level instance which is passed to individual classes.  Or have individual methods with atomic database operations internally create, use, and dispose of their data context objects.  Because multiple concurrent database contexts open across your application can lead to a variety of concurrency problems.

Comment: I see. So its better to call the context only as I use it. Thank you! I'll rework my application so that it doesn't do the looping call.

Comment: @JianYA: It's worth it as an exercise to start to define your "atomic" business operations.  Groups of operations which should succeed or fail in their entirety.  For example, "place an order" might be an atomic operation, and may consist of inserting/updating several records in a database as well as other logic.  That operation would create a DB context, perform its DB interactions, commit the transaction, and dispose of the DB context object.

Comment: Doesn't this sound like defining a single database context in the class so that those operations can be done in one go compared to having a db context in each method.

Comment: @JianYA: Depends on how the class is defined and used.  Normally I'd have my classes expose high-level business operations as public methods, and within those methods they would wrap the steps of the operation in a `using` block with a DB context.  Those individual steps might be extracted into private methods which acceps the DB context as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not proper way to use database context. In the most cases database context shouldn't be a member of your class (or your class should be `IDisposable` at least), because it should live as short as possible, and should be correctly disposed:

```
public class ProgramsData
{
    private FieldsData fieldsData = new FieldsData();
    private PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();

    public ProgramsData()
    {

    }

    public void SomeMethodWhichWorksWithData()
    {
        using (AutoPrintDbContext dbContext = new AutoPrintDbContext())
        {
            // work with database context here, try to make it as short as possible
        }
    }
}
```

The `StackOverflowException` is unrelated to database context at all, because your classes create new instances of each other in the infinite loop.

For example, `ProgramsData` creates new instance of `PrinterData` in this line:

```
private PrinterData printerData = new PrinterData();
```

and then `PrinterData` creates a new instance of `ProgramsData` in this line:

```
private ProgramsData programsData = new ProgramsData();
```

And then it repeats until it crashes the program.